# Question on proof of Basu's theorem?

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been trying to follow this proof on Basu's theorem-http://sankhya.isical.ac.in/search//64a3/64a3032.pdf . But Im getting stuck. The proof is on page 511. $T$ is a boundedly complete statistic and $U$ is an ancillary statistic. We are trying to show independence conditionally. The part that confuses me is this- $$P(U ≤ u,T ≤ t\mid θ) = E[g(T)I_{T≤t}\mid θ] = pP(T ≤ t\mid θ) = P(U ≤u)P(T ≤t\mid θ)$$ for all $\theta$. 
$g(T)$ is defined as $$g(T)=P(U ≤ u\mid T = t) = E[I_{U≤u}\mid T = t]$$
$p$ is defined as $$ p = P(U ≤ u) = P(U ≤ u\mid θ)$$

The above supposedly follows from iterated expectations. But I thought iterated expectations meant $E[E[g(T)\mid Y]=E[g(T)]$ But here we have the $I_{T≤t}$ term which means how could we apply iterated expectations? Even if we apply it anyway,
$$P(U ≤ u,T ≤ t\mid θ) = E[g(T)I_{T≤t}\mid θ]=E[E[I_{U≤u}\mid T = t]I_{T≤t}\mid θ]=E[I_{U≤u}I_{T≤t}\mid \theta]$$ I dont see how we go from here to $pP(T ≤ t\mid θ)$? It seems like Im back to the same thing as $P(U ≤ u,T ≤ t\mid θ)$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In that proof, it stated that "The bounded completeness of T
now implies that $P[g(T) = p|\theta] = 1$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$" before that calculation. So that's why $E[g(T)I_{T\leq t}|\theta] = pE[I_{T\leq t}|\theta]$

Comment: Thats what I thought at first, but why does this follow from iterated expectation law. No iterated expectation law was used there, just substitution?

Comment: I thought you already understand the iterated expectation part as you typed that line. See the answer below (the middle term should be indicator inside the inner expectation).

Comment: Got it, Not having the indicator functions was confusing me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe iterated expectation is being applied in the first not second equality, $P_\theta(U ≤ u,T ≤ t) = E_\theta[E_\theta[U\le u,T\le t\mid T]] = E[g(T)I_{T≤t}\mid θ]$. The second equality follow since $g(T)$ is almost surely constant by completeness, i.e., just linearity of expectation, $g(T)=p$ a.s. (all $\theta$) implies $E_\theta[g(T)I_{T\le t}]=E_\theta[pI_{T\le t}].$